# Error by Gradle plugin in Visual Studio Code: Unable to resolve class

Tags: gradle, visual-studio-code

I have some `gradle` project in `VS Code`.

`VS Code` version: `1.60.2`
`Gradle Tasks` extension version: `3.8.0`

The build config of `gradle` successfully compiling to Java project, that we can see in `Output` of `Gradle Task`:

```
[info] Build file changed: /home/helga/repos/attachmentsservice/build.gradle
[info] Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
[info] JVM Args: --add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant
[info] Gradle User Home: /home/helga/.gradle
[info] Gradle Version: 6.8
[info] CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 208ms
[info] Found 45 tasks
```

And also `gradle` `task` by itself successfully build by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + B`:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
11 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

But! `Visual Studio Code` displays an error on the `import` in `build.gradle`:

[image]

What can be a problem?